# Updating account information using PHP and HTML forms

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP page with a HTML form and PHP on it. It asks the user to change their username and for it to change in the database. I have some code but it doesn't quite work and I'm stuck as to what I need. Could someone please give me some ideas?

HTML

```
<form id="edit" method="POST" action="">

    <h1>
        <label for="username">Username *</label>
        <input id="username1" type="text" name="username1" value=""/>
    </h1>

    <h1>
        <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </h1>

</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['edit'])){
    $username = $_POST["username1"];

    $id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
    $query = "UPDATE user SET username = '$username' WHERE id = '$id'";
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?  How does the form access your PHP script?

Comment: you made a query. good. then you have to do something with it. and btw you have to do something with user input either

Comment: $query = "wish wish jellyfish" -- doesn't make it happen

Comment: Well, if this is all you have, you are missing a way of storing the data. You create three variables with strings in them, and then terminate the script. Where do you think you need to use `$query`? If you google on that, what do you find?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['edit']))` doesn't mean much if the form isnt NAMED "edit". therefore you should try `<form name="edit" method="POST" action="">` or `<form name="edit" id="edit" method="POST" action="">` if you need to keep the id too. Moreover, you're not querying at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask for `$_POST['username']` instead of `$_POST['edit']`.

And your query must be executed by mysqli or PDO.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['username1'])){
    $username = $_POST["username1"];

    $id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
    $query = "UPDATE user SET username = '$username' WHERE id = '$id'";
    mysqli_query($database_con, $query);
}
?>
```

But these method is unsecure, because $username and $id could contain SQL-Injection.

Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "databasename");
if (isset($_POST['username1'])){
    $username = $_POST["username1"];

    $id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE user SET username = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("si",$username,$id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```